# Implement Soap Based Services with wsdl format in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, web-services, soap

I have to implement the XML base soap service in my iOS application.i have goggled the things but dint find proper implementation. here is my URL of XML based WSDL service.

```
http://www.XXX.XX.XX/IntegrationService/MobileAppServicePort?wsdl
```

> following is the response when we call this service in SOA Client

```
Service name: MobileAppIntegrationService
Description: undefined
Targetnamespace: http://integration.XXX.XXXX.XXX.XX/
Operations: (please choose one of the listed operations)
1. Operation: getNewsDetails
2. Operation: getNewsList
3. Operation: login
4. Operation: getRulesList
```

now can any one please tell me how can i implement this kind of web-service to post or get the data from above operations as i have never been to this XML based soap service.

we have tried following thing to use one opertaion of CreateUser

```
soapMessage = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><getCountriesList xmlns=\"http://integration.esi.dtps.gov.ae/\"></getCountriesList></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

    //Now create a request to the URL
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@""]; //<--
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    //ad required headers to the request
    [theRequest addValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];//<--
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];//<--
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

and we are confused that what to add in `"HOST" "SOAPACTION" & "URL"`. can anyone please guide.

Comment: What you have tried ????

Comment: whatever we have googled they using some third party library.@Leena

Comment: what's about below link http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/ or https://github.com/priore/SOAPEngine